# Jackson JsonMappingException cannot instantinate

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, retrofit2

I am downloading and parsing this json with retrofit 2 and jackson converter

```
`{
  "message": "Action complete.",
  "successCode": 0,
  "data": {
    "miscellaneous": {
      "_id": "5678efcbcf5a5dc54f401eb9",
      "supportEmailDetails": {
        "body": "google.com",
        "subject": "google.com",
        "email": "google@gmail.com"
      },
      "supportPhone": "12345667899",
      "tempClickStaffingAgreementURL": "google.com"
    }
  }
}`
```

but it is giving me the following **error**:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable
>   constructor found for type [simple type, class
>   modals.MMiscellaneous$Miscellaneous]: can not instantiate from JSON
>   object (missing default constructor or creator, or perhaps need to
>   add/enable type information?)  at [Source:
>   java.io.InputStreamReader@1b44a0a3; line: 1, column: 72] (through
>   reference chain:
>   modals.MMiscellaneous["data"]->modals.Data["miscellaneous"])

I had generated the pojo with the help of http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ and created a single file, with all the generated class as enclosed

but when i generate the pojo class with the help of //https://timboudreau.com/blog/json/read  sites it gives me proper result with jackson,

i had tried to implement every result of internet to solve this issue but failed, so help me in resolving this issue

This is my java code,

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnyGetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAnySetter;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "message",
    "successCode",
    "data"
})
public class MMiscellaneous {

@JsonProperty("message")
private String message;
@JsonProperty("successCode")
private Integer successCode;
@JsonProperty("data")
private Data data;
@JsonIgnore
private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new    HashMap<String, Object>();

/**
 * No args constructor for use in serialization
 *
 */
public MMiscellaneous() {
}

/**
 *
 * @param message
 * @param successCode
 * @param data
 */
public MMiscellaneous(String message, Integer successCode, Data data) {
    this.message = message;
    this.successCode = successCode;
    this.data = data;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The message
 */
@JsonProperty("message")
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

/**
 *
 * @param message
 * The message
 */
@JsonProperty("message")
public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The successCode
 */
@JsonProperty("successCode")
public Integer getSuccessCode() {
    return successCode;
}

/**
 *
 * @param successCode
 * The successCode
 */
@JsonProperty("successCode")
public void setSuccessCode(Integer successCode) {
    this.successCode = successCode;
}

/**
 *
 * @return
 * The data
 */
@JsonProperty("data")
public Data getData() {
    return data;
}

/**
 *
 * @param data
 * The data
 */
@JsonProperty("data")
public void setData(Data data) {
    this.data = data;
}

@JsonAnyGetter
public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
    return this.additionalProperties;
}

@JsonAnySetter
public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
    this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
}


@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "miscellaneous"
})
public class Data {

    @JsonProperty("miscellaneous")
    private Miscellaneous miscellaneous;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public Data() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param miscellaneous
     */
    public Data(Miscellaneous miscellaneous) {
        this.miscellaneous = miscellaneous;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The miscellaneous
     */
    @JsonProperty("miscellaneous")
    public Miscellaneous getMiscellaneous() {
        return miscellaneous;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param miscellaneous
     * The miscellaneous
     */
    @JsonProperty("miscellaneous")
    public void setMiscellaneous(Miscellaneous miscellaneous) {
        this.miscellaneous = miscellaneous;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}


@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "_id",
        "supportEmailDetails",
        "supportPhone",
        "tempClickStaffingAgreementURL"
})
public class Miscellaneous {

    @JsonProperty("_id")
    private String Id;
    @JsonProperty("supportEmailDetails")
    private SupportEmailDetails supportEmailDetails;
    @JsonProperty("supportPhone")
    private String supportPhone;
    @JsonProperty("tempClickStaffingAgreementURL")
    private String tempClickStaffingAgreementURL;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public Miscellaneous() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param supportPhone
     * @param Id
     * @param tempClickStaffingAgreementURL
     * @param supportEmailDetails
     */
    public Miscellaneous(String Id, SupportEmailDetails supportEmailDetails, String supportPhone, String tempClickStaffingAgreementURL) {
        this.Id = Id;
        this.supportEmailDetails = supportEmailDetails;
        this.supportPhone = supportPhone;
        this.tempClickStaffingAgreementURL = tempClickStaffingAgreementURL;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The Id
     */
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public String getId() {
        return Id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Id
     * The _id
     */
    @JsonProperty("_id")
    public void setId(String Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The supportEmailDetails
     */
    @JsonProperty("supportEmailDetails")
    public SupportEmailDetails getSupportEmailDetails() {
        return supportEmailDetails;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param supportEmailDetails
     * The supportEmailDetails
     */
    @JsonProperty("supportEmailDetails")
    public void setSupportEmailDetails(SupportEmailDetails supportEmailDetails) {
        this.supportEmailDetails = supportEmailDetails;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The supportPhone
     */
    @JsonProperty("supportPhone")
    public String getSupportPhone() {
        return supportPhone;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param supportPhone
     * The supportPhone
     */
    @JsonProperty("supportPhone")
    public void setSupportPhone(String supportPhone) {
        this.supportPhone = supportPhone;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The tempClickStaffingAgreementURL
     */
    @JsonProperty("tempClickStaffingAgreementURL")
    public String getTempClickStaffingAgreementURL() {
        return tempClickStaffingAgreementURL;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param tempClickStaffingAgreementURL
     * The tempClickStaffingAgreementURL
     */
    @JsonProperty("tempClickStaffingAgreementURL")
    public void setTempClickStaffingAgreementURL(String tempClickStaffingAgreementURL) {
        this.tempClickStaffingAgreementURL = tempClickStaffingAgreementURL;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}


@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "body",
        "subject",
        "email"
})
public class SupportEmailDetails {

    @JsonProperty("body")
    private String body;
    @JsonProperty("subject")
    private String subject;
    @JsonProperty("email")
    private String email;
    @JsonIgnore
    private Map<String, Object> additionalProperties = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    /**
     * No args constructor for use in serialization
     *
     */
    public SupportEmailDetails() {
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param body
     * @param email
     * @param subject
     */
    public SupportEmailDetails(String body, String subject, String email) {
        this.body = body;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.email = email;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The body
     */
    @JsonProperty("body")
    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param body
     * The body
     */
    @JsonProperty("body")
    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The subject
     */
    @JsonProperty("subject")
    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param subject
     * The subject
     */
    @JsonProperty("subject")
    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return
     * The email
     */
    @JsonProperty("email")
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param email
     * The email
     */
    @JsonProperty("email")
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @JsonAnyGetter
    public Map<String, Object> getAdditionalProperties() {
        return this.additionalProperties;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setAdditionalProperty(String name, Object value) {
        this.additionalProperties.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: could you post how are your java classes defined?

Comment: @AntJavaDev, i had added my java code and tried to add also JsonCreator but still didn't work.

Comment: well i am not 100% sure about the Jackson annotations , but i suppose you should place the annotation only on field level  , or only at getter lever , or you could not place them at all , still its a bit awkward that it throws this exception , could you try to marshal a simpler json object , to check if it works

Comment: @AntJavaDev, it works well with other json pojo, only in this i am getting this error.

Comment: well i suppose there must be a difference when generating the pojo's from the [jsonschema](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) and when using the [timboudreau](https://timboudreau.com/blog/json/read) site  , otherwise , there might be a library mix up in your classpath , so you dont get a proper exception , because if you check the first site imports `fasterxml.jackson` , but the second one `codehaus.jackson`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use public *static* inner classes, otherwise new instances can't be created without an instance of the outer class.

```
public static class Miscellaneous {
...
}
```

Comment: yeap thats the issue , @Vikram Singh , you have copied the code from the second site , which uses inner classes , and tried to implement the same with the first example , which does not use inner classes , so the issue was of course with the constructor , didn't notice from the first place....+1

Comment: Yes, it worked but now i have to use static with every inner class

Comment: @VikramSingh correct. Or you don't use inner classes at all and pull them up to their own class files. That depends on context and preference. Anyway, using static inner classes is the solution to your problem, an accepted answer would be appreciated.